# Scripts folder which contains pip, easy_install missing in the fresh installation of python version 2.7 and 3.6 both

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, easy-install

Scripts folder which contains pip, easy_install missing in the fresh installation of python version 2.7 and 3.6 both.
Tried with fresh intallation one by one . but couldn't find any way to get Script folder which can help to install packages using pip command

Comment: Got the same problem with python3.6 installation on windows. Scripts folder is empty but the installation shows success and I can't find a log to see why.